# Can I ask questions about installation in SO?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

So far I have been asking questions about programming and it has been great.
I would like to ask a question regarding installing Linux on a Mac, and I wonder where is appropriate to do it. (Details are in the question itself).

Can I ask about this? Or where else?

Answer (score 14):

I'd try [Super User](https://superuser.com/), which is the site to go for general questions about software (and hardware) which are not specifically related to programming. Be sure to read their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/) before asking a question.

It might be on-topic for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) as well. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask, because your question is not

> - a practical, answerable problem that is *unique to software development*

(emphasis mine).

Comment: And note, run of the mill "how do I install X?" tend to get downvoted, since there's usually a guide on the software itself that tells you how. Normal research is required for these questions, too.

Answer (score 6):

@Glorfindel is right regarding general software, but the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *does* mention that "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic, so it should be ok to ask questions about installation, configuration, upgrading, and troubleshooting of *programming tools*. The standard rules about being specific as to what you are looking for and not requesting tool or tutorial recommendations still apply.

As @Braiam mentioned, a question about a programming tool must still be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", so a question about *installing* a programming IDE is more likely to be on-topic than a question about changing the title bar colors in such an IDE (unless an argument could be made that changing title bar colors in an IDE is meaningfully relevant to programming in it).

For example, if you are having trouble installing PHP on your Mac, you can post a question about it as long as you are specific as to what OS you are on (including version), what version of PHP you are trying to install, what procedure you are following, and what the result is (e.g. a specific error message, computer hangs, reboots infinitely, etc.).

Comment: software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is** a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Comment: @Braiam I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Installing your IDE is not unique to programming because installing software is not unique to programming.  The specific piece of software being installed doesn't automatically justify the issue as being on-topic.  Now, if there are specific aspects to installing the IDE that are unique to programming or unique to that piece of software, then you might have more of an argument to it being on-topic

Comment: @psubsee2003 it is true that installing software is not unique to programming, but installing *an IDE* is much more likely to be so because most IDE's are of marginal utility for non-programming tasks. It's sort of similar to the difference between asking for general help with learning to read or learning English as a Second Language and asking for help with understanding a specific RFC, manual, or spec. The fact that both kinds of questions might cover grammar, vocabulary, or spelling is a red herring.

Comment: What is the difference between installing, say, firefox vs vim vs eclipse on my Debian system? Hint: just the package name.

Comment: @RobertColumbia your comparison to ESL doesn't make sense. Installing software, no matter type of software, is not something that is unique to programming.  It doesn't require special knowledge that only a programmer can answer. The exception would be if there is special knowledge that only a programmer can address on installing the software.