# Why was a question about installing NetBeans closed for seeking recommendations?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

A [question about the revised process for installing NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305299/how-to-install-netbeans-9-on-windows-simple-way) was recently closed as being off topic:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it." – Samuel Liew

An image of the question is pasted below in case it gets deleted. A few points arising:

- This question is not seeking a recommendation for any "*off-site resource*". It is simply asking how to install NetBeans 9.0.
- Questions on NetBeans are at least potentially on topic since it is one of the "*software tools commonly used by programmers*".
- The question asked "*a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*".
- I thought that this question had been closed in error so I flagged the closure as being incorrect, but received no response.  There are now two votes to reopen the question.
- The question received 4 upvotes, and my answer received 10 upvotes. While that does not automatically mean it was a SO valid question, the post was clearly useful to quite a few people.
- The question was originally posted on Sep 13, but was closed as off-topic nearly three months later, about an hour after the question was edited. I don't recall the original wording of the question, but I believe it was substantively the same. Was the edit of the question what triggered the closure, and if so, what is the problem with the current wording of the question?
- While this is clearly not a programming question, there are thousands of questions on SO about installing and configuring IDEs such as NetBeans, Eclipse and Intellij IDEA. Is there a reduced tolerance for such questions now? Anecdotally, I increasingly see votes to close such questions even though they usually seem valid and useful to me.

[image: closedQuestion]

---

Update based on feedback to this question:

- I see that the original reason for closure of the question (*"Questions asking us to recommend..."*) that prompted this post has been quietly removed, without that even being mentioned in this thread! Who removed the original closure of the question? If it was a mistake at least own up to it!
- The question has now been *"put on hold as off-topic"* because it is about *"general computing hardware and software"* instead. I also disagree with that. The question clearly meets SO guidelines:

  - It relates to *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*.
  - The question asks a *"practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*, and also unique to NetBeans.
  - It is not a question about *"general computing hardware and software"*. It relates to NetBeans, and my answer provides information specific to NetBeans, an IDE supporting C, C++, Fortran, Java, Groovy and PHP development.
  - The SO question was not seeking recommendations or opinions, nor asking about any other "off-site resource".
- All that said, if the general consensus remains that the question is off-topic for SO, then I think SO should update [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to explicitly clarify the situation. If the linked question does not belong on SO then there are thousands more relating to the installation and configuration of IDEs that potentially do not belong on SO either. Users of SO should not have to carefully parse the wording of *"What topics can I ask about here?"* to determine whether their question is valid.

Comment: Your answer over there boils down to “unzip and run”. Do you really think that we need the question to remain open to receive more answers?

Comment: It's essentially asking for an installer, which is off-topic. FWIW if it is re-opened, I'll VTC.

Comment: _Your answer over there boils down to “unzip and run"._  => Well that is not the case, but regardless, how do you reconcile that with closing the question for seeking a recommendation for an off-site resource? The question isn't seeking recommendations at all.

Comment: _"It's essentially asking for an installer, which is off-topic."_ => Well that is not the case either. The question was asking "how to install NetBeans in a simple way". The question arose precisely because there is no longer an installer for NetBeans.

Comment: I think your best bet is to edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: I think it's the last sentence that's the problem. They should not be asking if there is some other thing they can use, they should just end it by asking how to do it.

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry at a question about an IDE being closed with "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: In the help center under [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it clearly states in the third bullet-point: `software tools commonly used by programmers` - so what's an IDE if not a tool?

Comment: @iLuvLogix: You should read also the next paragraph: "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above". Primary opinion based and looking for off-site resource are both such cases.

Comment: @jhpratt btw, it doesnt ask for an `installer` - the OP asks `how to install..` [Definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/installer) of an `installer`: **A program that installs software and prepares it for use.**

Comment: @BDL Good point there on the off-site resource

Comment: _"Primary opinion based and looking for off-site resource are both such cases."_ => Except the question was not seeking opinions at all, and the question was nothing to do with off site resources; it was about the changed process for installing NetBeans - an IDE with a user base of ~1.5 million users.

Comment: The question has run out of date and has become obsolete, basically. If you go to netbeans.org you get a proper link to Netbeans 9 downloads, nothing extraordinary about it. This may have not been the case when the question was asked back in September. That's just how it goes with software that is in a transitional phase.

Comment: @skomisa: I didn't state any opinion about the question till now. My point was just that  "software tools commonly used by programmers" does not necessarily mean that a question is on-topic. About the question: In my opinion, op is not looking for installation instructions for the zip but they are looking for a installer or other easy way to install (where easy is not specified). This is (imho) looking for a off-site resource.

Comment: @Gimby do you propose to close all obsolete questions? Are you going to request it on meta?

Comment: I do think that the question has value and I also think that it should be quite easy to reformulate it in a questions that clearly asks for instructions on how to install Netbeans.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338204/792066

Comment: @Braiam:  No it's not.  Installing an OS is fundamentally removed from installing a development tool like an IDE.

Comment: @Makoto that question is "Can I ask questions about installation in SO?" this question is "Can I ask questions about installation of X in SO?". X is irrelevant, so cut it out!

Comment: "SO then there are thousands more relating to the installation and configuration of IDEs that potentially do not belong on SO either" we will get to them.

Comment: This appears to be asking "where can I find this version of a software tool". While questions about tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic, off-site resource requests are *not*, even if the off-site resource is a programmin tool.

Comment: @TylerH I heard it many times when meta discuss failed audits " 'appears' doesn't work during review, you should go deep, know the context, it is not easy work ". And now buuum: "appears" should work. Sometimes.

Comment: Exactly how is _"Is there a simple way? Something like taking installer and install?"_ not asking to help find an installer? And are you aware that the **edit history** shows 1) what was edited and 2) who voted to reopen (the closure wasn't _quietly removed_, five people voted to reopen, and then five people voted to close it again).

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Not sure who is deleting all these comments, but as before, I'm not sure what your comment is trying to say, unfortunately.

Comment: `Apache NetBeans 9.0 is available for download from your closest Apache mirror. For this release no official installers are provided, please just download the binaries and unzip them. Officially, it is important that you verify the integrity of the downloaded files using the PGP signatures (.asc file) or a hash (.sha1 files). The PGP keys used to sign this release are available here.` <<-- This is literally on the link that the OP provided. A straightforward instruction on what needs to be done. And technically, the link with the above instructions **is** off-site resource.

Comment: It looks like they closed it again. Regardless of the extended discussion, and all the answers and comments that contend the closure of the question, some people will click the close button no matter what. Makes the whole discussion on Meta look pointless :(

Comment: @user There is really no consensus that it's on-topic. The two most upvoted answers have two different opinions, and the vote counts are really not that different. Many comments go in both directions. Don't be hopeless :p

Comment: `Users of SO should not have to carefully parse the wording of "What topics can I ask about here?" to determine whether their question is valid.` Yes, they should. The fact that they don't, is why there are so many questions being closed and deleted on an hourly basis..

Comment: ^This. SO is not a place for words that are not properly formatted or "carefully parsed" as mentioned.

Answer (score 28):

There's a tacit difference between developers *using* software, and developers *installing* software.  The long-standing premise has been that we at Stack Overflow don't directly deal with a developer *installing* software, because *who knows* how their environment is set up, or how their application elects to install things.  For instance, I'm on Linux and I use IntelliJ.  There are *at least* three different ways to accomplish this, and they all depend on how you want to go about installing it.

**On the other hand**, I could see how the laypeople of Super User may not know or care for installing such a niche and context-specific piece of software.  What's more telling is that the people who actually *use* this technology on a daily basis (for all intents and purposes) live *here*, and a question asking about how they should be installing their developer-oriented tools would seem perfectly on-topic.

With that, I personally do see this question as being on-topic for the site.  Developers that wish to use NetBeans should be able to ask questions about NetBeans (which includes installation) here, since someone here would have been able to do it.  This isn't generic software and this isn't likely going to be answerable by your average user at Super User.  More importantly, **this is *our* domain** of expertise, since we work with IDEs like this all the time.

If nothing else, it seems like the question should've been brought before the community ***before*** a unilateral decision to close it was made.

Comment: "before a unilateral decision to close it was made" there wasn't unilateral decision. 5 independent users voted to close that question. Are you saying that their votes doesn't count because you don't agree with them?

Comment: @Braiam:  Did you miss the part where a diamond moderator closed the question?

Comment: No, I didn't miss that. *You* missed the part where 5 users still said to close it as off topic with the same reason the moderator did! If the moderator has to wait for community consensus on something so clear cut as "installing X" questions, which aren't inherently on topic, then when the heck would a moderator use its powers? I can't wait to see all the drama if Shog implements the one vote and it's deleted. People will continue to whine.

Comment: @Braiam:   Ideally, on things that the community *can't* adjudicate, such as comments or refunding bounties or the like.  Moderators have broad powers and those powers should be exercised very carefully.  The fact that this question is in the middle of a Meta fight and is being voted to reopen and re-close is testament to the fact that, perhaps we should've talked about this first.

Comment: Well, we already discussed about [that.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338203/792066) [Twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330413/792066). If we follow that all questions related to software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic, then what wouldn't be covered? The sky would be the limit. We need to focus in what we know best: stuff only we can solve. The system administrator can figure how to install software in the programmer system.

Comment: The mod didn't close it with the same reason by the way. His reason was "asking for a recommendation / off-site resource".

Comment: The thing is... it's not particularly important that the question remains open or not. The answers that it can have it already have (more or less all of them repeating the same things) .When it's opened, it will never get a quality answer, because there is nothing to else to add to "unzip, run (and maybe make sure you have java installed)". At most it will keep getting answers repeating the same stuff. Current answers will go stale if the NB download page changes or NB zip structure changes in any way, or if they start providing an installer.

Comment: @Braiam: Two remarks.  First, the questions you link to are so far removed from the context of this question that it's mind boggling that you brought them up as case-in-point references to back your assertion that *this* kind of installation question should be forbidden.  Second, some developers *are* the system administrator on their machine (myself included, and I ***like*** it that way), and because this is a tool that developers use on a regular (enough) basis, it makes sense that this should be something that's permissible on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Braiam:  We have established that you lack both the domain knowledge and interest in answering the question.  I'm merely leaving the door open for those that *do* have the domain knowledge *and* the interest in answering the question.  The question itself is not poor, nor is it off-topic.  It's asking a reasonable thing since the process *really did* change from underneath everyone's feet.

Comment: My take in being off-topic is because the installation "issues" the asker had were not tool specific. There was not any special secret hand-shake to get it running, as many time there is for dev tools. In this case it is simply a case of _"go to download page, click on link, decompress file, run executable"_. It's the "turtle go left" of development tools questions. All the "problems" resolved, such as they are, are really userland problems, not dev problems. But either way, nothing really bad will happen when the question is opened again.

Comment: @yivi:  That's a "what-if" scenario.  We don't close questions based on "what-if"; we close them on objective *fact*.  If they do provide an installer, great!  We can update the answers.  Until they do, the fact remains that NetBeans users have to go installer-less.

Comment: @ayhan:  Immaterial; it was still a unilateral decision to close it.  Doesn't *help* the case that they closed it for an incorrect reason.

Comment: You're right Makoto, I didn't mean that we had to close it because of that. My bad for implying it. Just wanted to point out the low-value of the whole thing. The whole point of the question hinges on "there is no installer", when the only thing to do is _"download, unzip. run"_. It's fine that the OP and the other answerers chose to answer and help out the asker, and got all this upvotes in the process. It's just that I do not see any further value to be gotten from it. It's a great example of a very poorly reasearched and stated question, which revolves about doing things not dev specific.

Comment: From my point of view, the question is no different than asking about how to install a tool that **does** have an installer on a download page. Click download. Click install. Run.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree. "Asking for off-site resource" at least has a leg to stand on. Closing an IDE question with a message "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" is just ridiculous.

Comment: @yivi:  I see your point about the similarities but overall disagree given that IDE users can have a jarring experience when going between IDE versions.  Know that your point is at least understood and respected.

Comment: @yivi: _"The whole point of the question hinges on "there is no installer", when the only thing to do is "download, unzip. run"_. That is simply not true. You need to know how to verify the download's integrity, how to start NetBeans, how to respond to prompts when starting NetBeans for the first time, how to add alternative releases of Java, how to configure the default Java release, and how older installs are impacted. These things are not obvious, especially to students using NetBeans for the first time. **If you have never installed NetBeans please refrain from telling us how it's done.**

Comment: @skomisa:  Careful there.  Knowing how to verify the download's integrity is not a developer-specific concept.   Let's not take the opportunity of a defense of a question in and of itself as a land-grab to defend other parts of it which aren't *as* defensible.

Comment: @skomisa I **have** installed and used netbeans, thank you. Most of the things you list, if not all, are simply not necessary to run netbans. All the other parts you go about are not about _"how to install nb now there is no installer"_, but about verifying the download, and configuring certain aspects of the IDE. If you have java installed (which you do not mention in your answer), is simply a matter of downloading, unzipping, and running the appropriate file from "bin". With this I'm out, I don't know why are you taking this so personally. Good evening.

Comment: @Makoto: Agreed, and point taken. That said, I was specifically countering the false claim that _"the only thing to do is "download, unzip. run"_. Regardless of our opinions on the larger issue, I hope we can agree that we should verify the zip's integrity before unzipping it. I believe the other points I made were all specific to NetBeans installation. More broadly I want to challenge the claim that installing NetBeans is simply a matter of downloading and unzipping a file. It isn't.

Comment: @skomisa:  Be advised that *installing* the application really is little more than unzipping the archive and executing it.  Doing due diligence while installing it would be to checksum the file you get, which is a step many people skip.  Configuration is *wholly* divorced from installation because the app is *installed* if you're configuring it.  Like I said, be careful about using this as an opportunity to prop a defense of other indefensible claims.

Comment: @Makoto: Well of course that depends on what you mean by "install". I commented below that _Surely most developers would take a common sense approach, and understand that "installing software" also includes any necessary configuration._, but YMMV. And I don't necessarily agree that _"the app is installed if you're configuring"_ since part of "configuring" can frequently involve choosing which parts of the application you want to install. Software can be installed, and even downloaded, as a result of a configuration choice.

Comment: @yivi Regarding _"I don't know why are you taking this so personally."_, you made it personal because you edited my OP to insert your own views, which you could have done just as easily in a comment. Editing an OP to correct spelling and grammar errors is perfectly fine, but putting YOUR WORDS against MY NAME is not fine at all. That was unprofessional and unethical.

Comment: *"The long-standing premise has been that we at Stack Overflow don't directly deal with a developer installing software"* - I don't agree. A search for ["how do I install"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22how+do+i+install%22+is%3Aquestion) yields 3508 questions of which 3350 are open. You have to go to page 65 out of 67 to find any with negative score. These kind of questions have always been somewhat controversial, but the weight of community opinion is strongly in favor of allowing them.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  A developer installing software is different than a developer installing development tools.  We don't support devs asking about how to install Firefox, for example, but questions asking about an IDE are perfectly on-stream.

Comment: @Makoto We don't support devs asking how to *use* Firefox either. Your first paragraph was comparing questions about *using* software to ones about *installing* it, with the implication that the former were clearly acceptable and the latter generally not considered okay; in that context you're implicitly talking about programmer-specific software, aren't you?

Comment: @MarkAmery well, luckily I have a site to ask how to pimp up my emacs installation. HInt: I would never ask it in SO.

Comment: For me, it's the task/objective that defines whenever is on topic or not. Not who you are (programmers on a boat?) not what tools are you using (visual studio doesn't support italics for writing my novel?). The tools doesn't make the people, the actions does.

Comment: @Skomisa This is a collaboratively maintained and moderated website. Your posts will be edited, and possibly things you would not have said will be added, but that doesn't mean you suddenly have carte blanche as to how you act with other people. Accusations of unprofessionalism and lack of ethic sense are really overboard. And even more if **the edit was actually true**.

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

As mentioned the question **could** be edited so it's not unclear and off-topic. A clear statement of "How do I install the Netbeans 9?", that at least went through the trouble of actually downloading it first, would be a better, on-topic question. A poor, unresearched question, with very marginal utility. But on-topic nonetheless.

When a question requires editing by its author to be on-topic, we close the question until the author does so.

In my opinion, the original closure was appropriate, and it should now remain closed until edited by its author.

---

As much as it pains me to disagree with Makoto, I do believe this question is completely off-topic. And that the fact it deals with Netbeans is completely irrelevant.

Taking the question in isolation, without considering the existing answers:

> ## How to install Netbeans 9 on Windows simple way?

Even with the title we are off to a bad start. What does *"a simple way"*  even mean? What's meant with *"how do you install"*?. It almost looks a trick question, since there is no "installation" process" at all for Netbeans: You unzip in your location of choice and run the appropriate executable, if you have Java installed.

Then, the question itself, line by line:

> Apache NetBeans 9.0, released on the 29th of July, 2018.
>
> Installing 8.2 is really easy, you just go [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and download the installer.

First, a bunch of noise at the beginning. We can safely skip this.

> Installation of 9.0 is an enigma. The official site [here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) [...]

It points to the download page, and complains about an enigma. But on this same link it clearly says that ***"For this release no official installers are provided, please just download the binaries and unzip them"***. No "enigma" there, apparently.

Having had installed Netbeans, I can attest this is true. Download, unzip, run. The only "engimatic" part could have been finding the "bin" folder, for a very novice and uncurious user.

Did they have trouble finding this folder? Or trouble runnning the executables? Are they asking how to create a shortcut for the executables, something commonly done on Windows by an installer?

They simply do not say, and as happens many times with very basic questions, this makes it confusing.

If someone were to ask me *"how do I drink water from this glass?"* I think my first impulse would be to ask what they meant, not to say *"you raise it to your mouth, tilt it so water drops inside your mouth, and then swallow. please remember to stop for breathing and to stop when the glass is empty"*. Not saying that very basic questions are bad, but that sometimes they need some work to make them clear to a general audience (e.g. not the asker).

> [...] only provides either source or a Mac version.

The second to last line gives a hint that the whole problem was about *finding a download link*. Since they say: *"Only provides either source or a Mac version"*. Since we do know that the download page also include a link to the binaries, it looks that they just missed it. This would support the original closure as as *asking for offsite resources*, which was the original point of contention for this meta question.

> Is there a simple way? Something like taking installer and install?

The last line makes things look even worse, IMO. Since it makes it look like the user is looking for an alternative installer to use instead of unzipping, which would be seen as not simple enough.

All in all, between a simple misunderstanding to completely unclear to "get me an installer".

At best, I would have addressed the asker in comments to clarify (as the a couple commenters did), and wait until the question  looked better to write an answer, if at all. For the looks of it, answering in comments and deleting the question appeared to be a good course of action.

We've all missed things like this. Once pointed in the right direction, you shake your head in self-deprecation, delete the question, and move on.

---

Regarding the answers: those posted decided to interpret the question as "how to install" with some variance, and go over different aspects of download verification (very good thing to do, and great to mention in answers) and application configuration, while omitting other aspects of it. The answers are not the point of contention (although it's always better to clarify the question being answered, before or after answering, that's not what's being discussed here).

There is even a self-answer (heavily downvoted) where the user basically says how to download the files (!), decompress and execute the first time, glossing over the installation of Java libraries. With even a couple of "ignore this dialog and just click continue" instructions.

This last one could hopefully used to further illuminate the question asker intentions, although the conclusions are not particularly flattering.

---

The question is very poorly researched and confusingly stated; so it's no surprise different close reasons were chosen by different users. In the end, we all know that it's slightly more important that bad questions *are actually* closed that they are closed for the exact right reason, though.

I believe that the question is off-topic for being either: unclear, about topics which are not specific to programming (even if being applied to a developer tool it's about downloading and uncompressing a file), opinion based (*simple way*), or about an external resource (*where is the installer*).

Comment: I dunno...The fact that it's Netbeans and not Slack makes the distinction that much more important here.  If the real issue is how the question is phrased, then that sounds like a problem that edits are meant to solve and address.  My concern is that this position makes it look more like a question that isn't *liked* and less like a question which is explicitly off-topic.  I'm quite happy that you decided to disagree with me.  It reminds me that I, too, can be human and err.

Comment: As I see it, the question is just _How to install Netbeans 9 on Windows_ + a lot of noise. While you could say it could benefit from removing that noise, we probably should discuss if such a question could be on-topic here at all. The triviality argument is a bit true, though, this seems like such a trivial task it doesn't fit SO very well. Personally, I don't like the answers discussing file verification, because verifying file integrity is just loosely related to installing software and something that belongs on SU, not SO.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth we did. My duplicate precisely did that. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so

Comment: I asked this question not to trick anyone, if you go to the installation [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) and look through the text you would see `Mac OSX` being mentioned and and no mention of "Windows" How should I know that  `from a ZIP Archive` means `For Windows`? You cannot zip Mac version or Java Binaries. I google around and find "Building from source" tutorial that seems to be for windows but was not easy. That is why I asked for a simple way. Please ask more questions if needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Braiam That's a question about installing an OS, which is not a tool primarily used by programmers. Imo that's a bad dupe, installing an IDE is something only programmers do while installing an OS is not programming related at all imo.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth "*about installation* in SO?" What you want to install is immaterial. It's the same question whenever is an OS, a program or a door.

Comment: @Braiam _"My duplicate precisely did that."_ => hardly! Your alleged duplicate was specifically asking about _"installing Linux on a Mac"_. This meta question specifically relates to NetBeans - a widely used programming tool. You are comparing apples to oranges and claiming they are the same thing ("duplicate"). They are not.

Comment: @skomisa was about installing X. Installing is not a task non-programmers programmers are privy to. Software developing is.

Answer (score 6):

I **asked** the question because the official installation instruction was not clear. If you go to the installation [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) and look through the text you would see "Mac OSX" being mentioned and and no mention of "Windows". How should I know that "from a ZIP Archive" means "for Windows"? You can zip-up Mac version or `Java Binaries`! I googled around and find "Building from source" tutorial that seemed to be for windows but was not easy.

I **answered** my question because, that is how I'd like it to be explained for me. I was not happy with the answer. Because it did not emphasise the problems I saw even though it covered a lot.

Answer (score -2):

> *Apache NetBeans 9.0 is available for download from your closest*
>   *Apache mirror. For this release **no official installers are provided,***
>   ***please just download the binaries and unzip them***.
>
> *Officially, it is important that you **verify the integrity of the downloaded files using***
>   *the PGP signatures (.asc file) or a hash (.sha1 files). The PGP keys*
>   *used to sign this release are **available here**.*

The above is literally on the link that the OP provided on the third line of his question. A straightforward instruction on what needs to be done.

And technically, the link with the above instructions **is still** off-site resource regardless. The OP is basically providing a link and asking SO members to read it and explain it back to him again which is what you end up doing. You just expanded each instruction that was already there on the [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html).

For example:

- `downloading the **binaries** link and not the **source** link` which was instructed right on top of the two respective links.
- `verifying the integrity of the downloaded files` which was instructed a few lines after the respective links.

And both of the above instructions are not even scattered across the page but are mentioned within the same `Downloading` section itself which, excluding the *binaries/source* links and the note on Mac OSX, consists of just four lines. As I mentioned above, all you did was expand each instruction that was already there on the [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html).

The final point that you state regarding concurrently running two versions of Netbeans is the only thing in your question that was actually informative and not on the **already provided link** honestly.

Comment: On a header of my the Question there was a OS pointed out.This OS was not mentioned anywhere in official instructions. It means that these instructions were not relevant to the question. I did not ask `SO members to read it and explain it back`.

Comment: `For this release no official installers are provided, please just download the binaries and unzip them.`.

Comment: Yes, but this information is useless unless OS and Binary type is specified. It might be `Java Binaries` or `Ubuntu Binaries`. With this little professionalism in making tutorials I have no trust in the files ether. It may be a scam. That is why my question was about `Windows`, not about `Binaries`.

Comment: [1] There is nothing wrong _per se_ with questions involving off site resources. If there was then questions on (say) cloud computing, maven repositories or web scraping would be off limits. [2] The specific prohibition is for questions asking to **recommend or find** some **off site resource**, and the question did not do that; it simply asked how to install NetBeans in a simple way. [3] Part of the solution was to use a download link, but that was not part of the question. Therefore, voting to close the question for "asking us to recommend or find...other off-site resource" is incorrect.

Comment: Re _"all you did was expand each instruction that was already there on the link"_, that is false, but also beside the point. The issue is not the quality of the answers (which can be down-voted), but whether the question itself was _"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"_, and it was not. I would also mention that we don't know the state of the NetBeans page when the original question was asked. It has definitely changed since I provided my answer.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev how about fixing said documentation. https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans-website/pull/92

Answer (score -9):

Just because a question involves something involving programming, does **not** make it on topic for Stack Overflow. If there was no documentation, official or otherwise, for "how to install NetBeans 9" then both the question and its answers would be useful, but that's not the case.

The question itself is incredibly poor. It shows no research effort, in fact it demonstrates that the asker either did not read or understand the instruction on the NetBeans download page, that is *linked to in the question itself* that literally tells you what to do right there on the page, plus has a link to a video explaining the process.

Your answer is not much better; it's essentially the same instructions from the the very same download page, reformatted, and with some extra fluff about side-by-side installations and Java paths.

(What's interesting is that the person who asked the question [posted a self-answer very similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696939/70345), so I'm wondering if there's some sort of attempt at rep-farming going on here... although their answer is both late and currently at a hard -5, so if it was an attempt it went horribly wrong.)

Regardless, though, the question boils down to "how do I do this thing that is very clearly explained on the web page" and all answers are going to boil down to "here are the instructions from the same web page".

The question is not high-quality, the answers are never going to be high-quality, and the whole shebang should be nuked from orbit, nuked again, and then nuked a third time just to be certain. If it gets reopened, I'm VTC'ing for all I'm worth.

Comment: Your failure to actually link to the web page that supposedly provides all the necessary information, and your failure to quote the relevant text, is notable.

Comment: The page that provides the information is literally the page the asker linked to in their question...

Comment: This doesn't look very good.  Instead of a good-faith attempt at a discussion, you immediately lash out and attack kind of everyone in this scenario.  Instead of keeping the conversation constructive and objective, you declare that you'll simply VTC the question for all you're worth.  Jeez...

Comment: But that page doesn't contain all the information provided in the answers. Your claim is simply false. And why on earth do you feel the need to be so rude and nasty?

Comment: I asked this question because the official installation instruction was not clear (just as you say  `If there was no documentation`). That is why - if you go to the installation [link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) and look through the text you would see `Mac OSX` being mentioned and and no mention of "Windows" How should I know that  `from a ZIP Archive` means `For Windows`? You cannot zip Mac version or Java Binaries. I google around and find "Building from source" tutorial that seems to be for windows but was not easy. That is why I asked for a simple way. Thanks.

Comment: I answered my question because, that is how I'd like it to be explained for me. I was not happy with the answer. Because id did not emphasise the problems I saw. Thank you.

Comment: @Makoto Because there is no discussion to be had. Based on the facts, the question is objectively not a high-quality programming question, therefore not on topic, and therefore not deserving of reopening. As for "attacking" people, I think you're reading a little too much into my (admittedly brusque) tone.

Answer (score -16):

This is not offtopic "general software question" since related to developers tools. And answer provides interesting content too, not a "recommendation for a tool".

I have voted to reopen it. SO is moderated by us.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't give a sufficient justification of why the Q is on-topic. Saying it's related to "developer tools" is not sufficient, as an IDE is a developer tool but "What's the best IDE?" is off-topic. Yes, we moderate SO, but if you just want to assert that power, assert it by voting. An answer *here* must be at least an *attempt* at justification, not just a bald assertion.

Comment: Why you think that referencing something inapplicable like "opinion based" should explain everything?

Comment: This is your answer. It is your job to justify and defend it. If you don't want to do that, don't post an answer.  My downvote will remain until you add justification to the answer, based on the rules and norms of the site. I will not engage in further conversation or make further comments.

Comment: I do not see any reason why you have started it.

Comment: Hi Roman! Just add some lines from the help center under [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it clearly states in the third bullet-point: `software tools commonly used by programmers` That should do the trick ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix which still would be wrong since that comes with the conditional "**and is** a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**". Unziping an executable isn't unique to software development.

Comment: @Braiam While I fully agree on that point I still have the feeling that this question and its answers can help others with a similar issue and should therefore remain

Comment: @Braiam read the answers. There's more to it than simply unzipping, there's also some configuration to be done.

Comment: @Stijn I don't care what the answer is, but what the question is about. The question is about installing software, that's off topic. If someone wants to configure said software, **they should ask about that**. As it stands, the question is asking how to install the software, which by the own vendor is just "unzip them". That's all it takes to *install*. Why is anyone defending such a poorly researched question?

Comment: @Braiam why are you ignoring the "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" part? And poorly researched questions should be downvoted, not closed with a bogus reason.

Comment: @Stijn I read the answers and installed Netbeans. No extra configuration is needed. All the rest is simply extra information. The only required steps are _”unzip, run executable in bin directory”_

Comment: @Stijn because, I've heard that argument before and it doesn't hold water. Read the several previous meta post about this, like the one I marked this question as duplicated. That line is the defining quality of SO. A pure algo question isn't on topic, however you want to slice it; so it's a pure software tool question even if commonly used by programmers.

Comment: There are some users who do not care about answers and good content, they think that SO moderation is something like calculating by "table function" given as a physics law. Not a communication process, not a content creation process.

Comment: @Braiam Re _"The question is about installing software, that's off topic. If someone wants to configure said software, they should ask about that."_, you are sounding like a lawyer trying to win an argument. Surely most developers would take a common sense approach, and understand that _"installing software"_ also includes any necessary configuration.

Comment: @skomisa lawyer since Roman law understand that law is based on common principles, if they refuse to evaluate content "as interesting for other developers" - then they can't be named lawyers. P.S. there is of course other SO principle: "keep rating economics stable" but it is also absent in theirs argumentation. Only "table defined function".

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding why your answer is being downvoted. It's being downvoted not for its view, but for the lack of justitifcation of its view (though some others may have voted for the view as well). I agree that the question is on-topic, but your answer here doesn't offer any justification for why, thus my downvote.

Comment: @mason , downvotes on this my answer are not essential for me. the possibility to organize some discussion is much more important.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Fine, you can say you don't care about downvotes and that you want a discussion. But the downvotes are the discussion: they're trying to tell you something. Listen to it. Learn. Adjust.

Comment: @mason, those people are unhappy with "we are the moderators"  it is too bold for them. do you hear anything else? you see -15. but you do not know how much it was upvoted. and you even do not want to know. so may be you should listen, no? the closed quesion was reopened two times - listen it.

Comment: You missed my point. It’s. It about whether the question should be open or closed. I am talking about how your answer fails to address *why* it should be open or closed. That’s why I’m asking you to learn.

Comment: @mason to learn "why closed" from downvotes on my answer? you can't be serious.. Second, this is not a discussion "why closed", this is a discussion about  understanding moderation as a kind of "ocultism": "listen! you should learn the our Meta Consensus,  you could never succeed, may be it is too complex for you. Listen our sagas". My opinion: bad or good question should be stated in two sentences. Then vote. That is all. If you doctrine doesn't work for this case - nothing very critical - left it. There is no logic to close the same question N times.